# Взять содержимое с страницы

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть страница с содержимым {"result":"ok","contactId":"9563","contactCode1c":"","contactNamefull":"\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434","contactName":"\u0412\ u043b\u0430\u0434","contactNamelast":"\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442","contactNamemiddle":"","contactCompany":"","contactCompa nyID":0,"contactEmail":"","contactEmails":"","contactPhone":"0660785767","contactPhones":"","contactTypesex":"","contact Managerid":"3963","contactCdate":"2018-04-16}
Нужно присвоить переменной вот эти данные "contactId":"9563"
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. Спасибо большое заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//адрес сайта
$url = 'http://site.ru';

// получаем содержимое сайта
$json = file_get_contents($url);

// преобразуем в массив
$array = json_decode($json, true);

// выводим значение переменной contactId
echo $array['contactId'];
```

Comment: Скорее требуется просто вывод `echo $array['contactId'];`

Comment: Согласен, не совсем верно понял суть вопроса автора. Отредактировал

Comment: @skarb смотрите, есть такая страница http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/09/30/0026/3412/1727828/28/b98183b61f.jpg нужно взять из этой страницы "contactId":"9563" и занести в переменную.

Comment: @skarb :) хорошо...

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин так берите, в ответе автора просто первые строчки замените на: `$json = file_get_contents('ссылка на ваш сайт');`

Comment: @Manitikyl у меня же нет этих данных в коде "result":"ok",
    "contactId":"9563",
    "contactCode1c":"",
    "contactNamefull":"\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434",
    "contactName":"\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434",
    "contactNamelast":"\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442",
    "contactNamemiddle":"",
    "contactCompany":"",
    "contactCompa nyID":0,
    "contactEmail":"",
    "contactEmails":"",
    "contactPhone":"0660785767",
    "contactPhones":"",
    "contactTypesex":"",
    "contact Managerid":"3963",
    "contactCdate":"2018-04-16"}'; они на странице находятся, как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Так вы хотите взять информацию с другого сайта и занести значение переменной contactId в свой скрипт?

Comment: @skarb да, все верно.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин ну так яж вам ответил: `$json = file_get_contents('ссылка на ваш сайт');`. Ссылка-то на сайт имеется? просто вставьте, и после выполнения этой строчки у вас в переменной `$json` будет та самая строка. Убедитесь сами, проверьте :)

Comment: @Manitikyl ссылка вот такая http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: Владислав, отредактировал ответ

Comment: @Manitikyl суть в том что в содержимое сайта я парсю содержимое с другой страницы и вывожу на свой сайт. Содержимое моей страницы я скидывал ранее на скрине. Подскажите, можно ли не парсить содержимое внешней страницы на свой сайт, а просто взять тот id из внешнего сайта на свою страницу.

Comment: @skarb отлично, спасибо большущее. Все работает.

Comment: @skarb подскажите, если такое значение "Kolichestvobalov","value":"200" Как его взять?